# Doubt related to example 4 of section 14 chapter 2 of Munkres Topology book

Tags: general-topology, order-topology

The example goes as follows

> The set X = {1,2} × $\mathbb{Z^+}$ in the dictionary order is another example of an ordered set with a smallest element. Denoting $1×n$ by $a_n$ and $2×n$ by $b_n$
> We can represent X by $a_1,a_2,..$;$b_1,b_2,...$
> The order topology on X is *not* a discrete topology. Most one point sets are open but there is an exception — the set {$b_1$}. Any open set containing $b_1$ must contain a basis element about $b_1$ and **any basis element containing $b_1$ contains the points of the $a_i$ sequence**

---

I have no idea how to prove the text in bold so as to understand why does the basis element have to contain the points of the $a_i$ sequence any help would be appreciated

Sincerely,
Aditya

Comment: Cam you draw a picture of the space arranged on a single line in order? That might help you visualize what a neighborhood of $b_1$ looks like.

Answer (score 1):

Recall that basis elements for the order topology are the *open intervals*, so in this case, for $b_1$ to be in $(r,s)$, with $r,s \in X$, $r < s$, it is necessary (by definition) that $r < b_1$, so that $r = a_n$ for some $n \in \mathbb N$, as well as $s > b_1$, so that $s = b_k$ for some $k \in \mathbb N$ as well. But this implies, for example, that $a_{n+1} \in (r,s) = (a_n,b_k)$ as the author claims.

Note that the semi-open intervals of the form $[a_1, x)$ are also open here, but this case is not problematic.

Comment: Ohh so the **in dictionary order** makes it happen?

Comment: Yes, @AdityaEkbote , here the dictionary order just means that $(a,b) < (c,d)$ if and only if $a < c$ or $a=c$ and $b<d$ (similar to a linguistic dictionary). In other words, elements of the form $a_j$ always come before elements of the form $b_k$.